# U.Desktop 21.04 & XUbuntu 21.10 install Ok but don't boot, message "no bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

Tags: boot, xubuntu, bios, 21.04, 21.10

I'm installing Ubuntu on Acer Aspire 7720G (some years old, this is recycling) 4GB RAM (the max), SSD 240GB MBR.

As a test, Windows 10 did install and boot perfectly on it.

Ubuntu Desktop recognized the SSD, as well as BIOS (that by the way I Upgraded from 1.21 to 1.45).

Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 live DVD takes time to get up the screen, but it does.
Then the Install process takes also time, but it also does, ending up to the reboot and DVD Eject.

But the reboot does not boot, after the BIOS screen, I have the message
"no bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

XUbuntu 21.10 live DVD takes normal time to get up the screen.
Then the Install process takes also normal time, ending up to the reboot and DVD Eject.

Could this come from the Acer BIOS, which is not UEFI, and the boot loader has only UEFI boot mode?
The SSD has after installation a partition marked as boot.

How could I go further?
(I'm trying LTS20.04, maybe more complete for old hardware)

Thank You in advance!

EDIT: With the LTS 20.04, It works very well and the boot on the disk is OK!

Comment: How it boots is how it installs. So, if you were able to boot and install then it has the required bootloader. Entirely expected because the Ubuntu ISO boots either way. The problem is when using Rufus with its default mode that requires users to select one or the other.

Comment: If you can boot to a live system in mbr mode you could just reinstall grub.

Comment: The live DVD boots and then I asked to install, the install procedure successes to install, when prompted click "Reboot" then after removing the live DVD, when reboot, BIOS Screen, then the "no boot device" message. But partitions are well created, and one is with the "boot" flag on the disk.